# How to copy a single mondodb document from one collection to another

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Is there an easy way to copy a single document from one collection to another.Without uploading data to the client.

Comment: there are multiple ways to do it, using `mongoexport` & `mongoimport` or using code as it's just a single doc, but it all depends on what type of operation you're doing (is it a batch or one time), what do you mean by *Without uploading data to the client* ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to say: do copy doc with _id:"some id" from one collection to another.Of course it is possible to get data by find_one, then insert thet data to another collection, bat don't want do this. mongod version v3.6.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe with this few lines

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson import ObjectId

source = MongoClient("...").db.col
target = MongoClient("...").db.col

obj = source.find_one({"_id": ObjectId("..")})
target.insert_one(obj)
```

Comment: Yes. For mongodb version lower then 4.2 this solution. Starting with version 4.2 the '$merge' stage is included in it, which outputs the aggregation pipeline results to a collection. In my situation I deside to upgrade Mongod til version 4.2.3.